# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? 6

Tags: пунктуация

В планах: увеличение производительности и количества выпускаемых изделий – для этого заказаны и в скором времени будут запущены в эксплуатацию вертикально-фрезерные обрабатывающие центры, новые токарно-винторезные станки, – обновление и усовершенствование парка сварочного и наплавочного оборудования, расширение возможностей и увеличение объема по количеству выпускаемых изделий покрасочного оборудования, для повышения качества выпускаемых изделий – приобретение оборудования лазерной маркировки и введение системы QR-кодирования, модернизация производственных участков и улучшение условий труда.

Нужно ли второе тире и запятая перед ним? Или лучше все заключить в скобки?

Comment: Вставная конструкция в скобках, по-моему, будет смотреться лучше. Но если два тире, то перед вторым тире запятая обязательна, так как она разделяет однородные члены:увеличение, обновление и усовершенствование...

Comment: Да, и я так тоже подумала...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Содержание текста не вполне ясно и не воспринимается на слух, поэтому предлагается следующее **редактирование** (если содержание понято  правильно):

**В планах предприятия значится**: **увеличение** производительности и количества выпускаемых изделий,   для чего заказаны и в скором времени будут запущены в эксплуатацию вертикально-фрезерные обрабатывающие центры и  новые токарно-винторезные станки; **обновление** и усовершенствование парка сварочного и наплавочного оборудования;  **расширение** возможностей и увеличение объема по количеству выпускаемых изделий покрасочного оборудования; **приобретение** оборудования лазерной маркировки и введение системы QR-кодирования с целью повышения качества выпускаемых изделий; **модернизация** производственных участков и улучшение условий труда.

Comment: Спасибо, но хочется знать, допустимо ли оформить вставку **для этого заказаны и в скором времени будут запущены в эксплуатацию вертикально-фрезерные обрабатывающие центры, новые токарно-винторезные станки** двумя тире с запятой? Это соответствует правилам?

Comment: Можно, если однородные члены разделять запятой, в этом случае вставка будет относиться к одному однородному члену. Но в приведенном предложении лучше ставить точку с запятой, иначе границы между смысловыми частями будут неясно обозначены.